# why samsung tabs (and few others) not supported on google play for my app?

Tags: android, google-play

I have seen several posts on the subject, but seems like there is little information on how to exactly determine why certain devices appear as "unsupported" for my published app on Google Play....  The app has no country filter, by the way. Any idea how to find the root of the problem?

Below is the output of 'aapt dump badging xxxxx.apk':
(I replaced the package name with 'xxxxx')
Note the app uses Urban Airship SDK for push via C2DM, which requires several of the permissions below.

tnx

```
package: name='xxxxx' versionCode='4' versionName='1.2.1'
sdkVersion:'10'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.CALL_PHONE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'xxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
uses-permission:'com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
application-label:'xxxxx'
application-label-he:'xxxxx'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='xxxxx' icon='res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='xxxxx.ui.SplashActivity'  label='xxxx' icon=''
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.network'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.landscape'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'he'
densities: '160' '240'
```

...and here is the list of Samsung devices (as of today) that are marked as unsupported in Google Play:

```
Behold II(sgh-t939)
Europa(GT-I5500)
GT-I5500M(GT-I5500M)
GT-I5700L(GT-I5700L)
GT-I5800L(GT-I5800L)
GT-N8005(p4noterf)
GT-P1010(GT-P1010)
GT-P1013(GT-P1013)
GT-P3108(espressorfcmcc)
GT-P6210(GT-P6210)
GT-P6211(GT-P6211)
GT-P6810(GT-P6810)
GT-P7300B(GT-P7300B)
GT-P7320(GT-P7320)
GT-P7500D(GT-P7500D)
GT-P7500M(GT-P7500M)
GT-P7500R(GT-P7500R)
GT-P7501(GT-P7501)
GT-P7503(GT-P7503)
GT-P7511(GT-P7511)
Galaxy(gt-i7500)
Galaxy Note 10.1 WIFI(p4notewifiww)
Galaxy Player(YP-G1)
Galaxy Player(YP-G70)
Galaxy Player(YP-GB1)
Galaxy Player(YP-GB70)
Galaxy Player(YP-GS1)
Galaxy Tab(SHW-M180K)
Galaxy Tab(SMT-i9100)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(GT-P7500)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SC-01D)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SCH-I905)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SHW-M300W)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SHW-M380K)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SHW-M380S)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SHW-M380W)
Galaxy Tab 10.1v(p3)
Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 WiFi(espressowifi)
Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus(SGH-T869)
Galaxy Tab 8.9(GT-P7300)
Galaxy Tab 8.9(GT-P7310)
Galaxy Tab 8.9(SGH-I957)
Galaxy Tab2 10.1(espresso10wifi)
Galaxy Tab™ 10.1(SGH-T859)
Galaxy Tab™ 7.7(SCH-I815)
Moment(sph-m900)
SCH-P739(SCH-P739)
SCH-i705(espressovzw)
SGH-I957D(SGH-I957D)
SGH-I957M(SGH-I957M)
SHV-E140K(SHV-E140K)
SHV-E140L(SHV-E140L)
SHV-E140S(SHV-E140S)
SHW-M180W(SHW-M180W)
SHW-M305W(SHW-M305W)
SHW-M430W(SHW-M430W)
SHW-M480W(p4notewifiany)
YP-G50(Non telephony)(YP-G50)
unknown(GT-P7510)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are requesting the `CALL_PHONE` permission. Unless you have `android:required="false"` on this, your app will only be installable on devices that have telephony capability. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Comment: great answer, but what if I'm asking for that permission in the run-time ?!!